# How to reuse Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

How could we reuse Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler to avoid it's new/delete for each request?

Comment: I don't think you should.  You run the risk of inadvertently having one request affect another.  You could however, roll your own factory that has a pool of them if you can guarantee no contamination.

Comment: Of course all handlers must be ready for a multi-threaded environment.
We have own factory but provided handler goes to std::unique_ptr and thus freed by poco. After poco calls handler's destructor it considered dead and can not proceed even if override the delete operator

Comment: You would have a custom destructor that would return the object to the pool.  The other option is to roll your own class with a custom `run` method